# laravel 5.2 yield and section not working correctly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My homep.blade.php

```
@yield('content')
```

My body.blade.php

```
@extends('Home.homep')

@section('content')
<p>This is my body content.</p>
@stop
```

when i run the code page is being empty its not working

Comment: homep.blade.php - public/Home/homep.blade.php? this path?

Comment: yes views/Home/homep.blade.php

Comment: try with `@endsection` instead of `@stop` in `body.blade.php`

Comment: i already tried nothing change

Comment: what is the path of your Home folder?

Comment: /laravel-test/views/Home/homep.blade.php

Comment: do it like:- `/laravel-test/resources/views/Home/homep.blade.php`. place the view folder inside resources folder and if resources folder already has views folder than place Home folder inside views folder.

Comment: i havent notice resources folder before sorry it was already in /laravel-test/resources/views/Home/

Comment: Home folder is already in views folder

Comment: ohkay.. post your `homep.blade.php`

Comment: i already did :D thats all and some html tags only @yield('content')

Comment: did you extended the `layouts.app` in `homep.blade.php`?

Comment: i dont understand what do you mean

Comment: Are you sure your 'body.blade.php' have proper extension?

Comment: yes  i am sure  about that

Answer (score 0):

inplace of @stop write @endsection i am sure it will not give any error.

Comment: i already tried that and im not getting any error im getting just empty page

Comment: send your layout file code and your folder structure.

Comment: folder structure http://i.hizliresim.com/WDbLv8.png and im not sure what do you mean saying layout file i think your meaning this one http://i.hizliresim.com/Az3drv.png

Comment: layout file means the file in wich you declare yield('content')

Comment: its working for me but here it is i uploaded again https://ibb.co/mnWfE8
https://ibb.co/e5VJ1o

Comment: i did but nothing change same blank page

Comment: i cant see the content

Comment: does not display anything in section

Comment: if you have any time can i add you c9.io workplace to look ?

Comment: do you have c9.io account name or mail ?? for add you

Comment: there isnt another way to add you :(